# AWS API Gateway fails while invoking backend API using private ip address

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I have created public API using AWS api gateway with the resource `cars` and a `GET` method. I also have backend API,`/api/routing`, that is hosted on EC2 windows instance.  The backend API only accepts `POST` request and used for routing the request based on some header values.

In integration request i also have Mapping Template setup so it can POST data to `api/routing`

So  the integration request for `cars` public API looks like below

[image]

The Inbound rules for EC2 instance

[image]

**Issue**
The Endpoint URL is using private ip of EC2 instance. When i Test `cars` api i get error

`Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address`

*If i change the Endpoint Url to use **public ip address** then its working as expected*

Eventually, i would like to access backend API using private-ip. The EC2 instance is a free instance that AWS created.

I understand that if i have VPC then in API Gateway i need to setup VPC Links, but I have not created any VPC.(unless aws by default creates one).

Comment: AWS has created default [VPC](https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-east-1#vpcs:sort=VpcId) for you. You will need to use VPC [links](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html) for integration with private subnets.

Comment: i tried creating NLB as per the article and configured VPC Link. Only difference is i created `internal` NLB instead of `public`. Because I think, the client for EC2 instance is API Gateway. However that did not work

Answer (score 1):

found it. After creating VPC link I was still selecting `Integration Type` as `HTTP`..it should be `VPC Link`